# How to use a different table on an if (like) conditon in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables
First table(day) just holds values, ie

```
uid,title
1, Mon
2, Tue
3, Wed
etc,etc
```

The second table (lookup) uses the first table

```
uid,day_id,date,status,tech_id
1, 1,2012-01-01, 1,700
2, 2, 2012-01-02, 0,700
etc,etc
```

The third table (template) uses the first table

```
uid,day_id,status,tech_id
1, 1, 1,700
2, 2, 0,700
3, 3, 0,700
```

In reality, each table holds a little more info that is shown, but that data is irrelevant for now.

What im attempting to do, is perform all the steps in a single SQL function rather than relying on code. Im trying to make the SQL function use the template table instead of the lookup table if there is no entry for that day

In psudocode:

```
column 1 = * from days
column 2 = status from(if (template != null, use template)elseif(lookup != null, use lookup)else(null))
where tech_id=700
```

Is this at all posible in MySQL? If so, how? I've been trying to do it with INNER/LEFT(outer) joins and sub-queries, but so far to no avail :(

Comment: okay, can you explain more what you mean (use template), display all the rows of this table ?

Comment: I think what you wish to achieve is something which JOIN() function of MySQL covers. Read about it here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Function/Function-In-Join.htm

Comment: @hjpotter92 There is no `JOIN()` *function*; just SQL DQL with various relational algebra operations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the COALESCE function:

```
SELECT d.*, COALESCE(SELECT status FROM lookup WHERE day_id = d.id, SELECT status FROM template WHERE day_id = d.id) as status
FROM day AS d
WHERE etc, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit i did figure it out, its a little bit ineloquent, but it works.

As this is being executed by PHP there can be variables, replace $tech_id with 700

```
SELECT da.*,
        (SELECT status FROM lookup AS lo WHERE tech_id=$tech_id  AND da.uid = lo.day_id) as lookup,
        (SELECT status FROM template AS te WHERE tech_id=$tech_id AND da.uid = te.day_id) as template
        FROM day AS da
```

It does it in two separate columns, but thats ok enough for now.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work. It uses the [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.

```
SELECT day.uid, day.title, COALESCE(lo.status, te.status) AS status
FROM day
LEFT JOIN lookup lo ON lo.day_id = day.uid
LEFT JOIN template te ON te.day_id = day.uid
WHERE lo.tech_id = $tech_id
   OR te.tech_id = $tech_id
```

Basically this builds a large flat set and then chooses the first non-null column out of `lo.status` or `te.satus` for each record. The `LEFT JOIN` means that the added columns (e.g. `status` or `tech_id`) may be `NULL` if the respective tables were missing records that joined on `day.uid`. Note the use of `OR` as `tech_id` in either case may also be `NULL` at this point. (The query above works on the premsie that `(day_id,tech_id)` is a candidate key for the lookup and template tables.)

Comment: Almost works perfectly, the problem is day doesn't have a tech_id value, so what occurs is instead of all days values being returned, it only returns if lookup or template has a value for that tech_id....

Comment: @Mattisdada That is correct. `OR (lo.tech_id IS NULL AND te.tech_id IS NULL)` could be trivially appended to the above if it was desired that sometimes `status` could be `NULL`.